# Prometheus regex match on different labels

Tags: prometheus, promql

I want to do a filter in prometheus based on all labels. Say if my labels in prometheus are instance, cpu, mode for the query node_cpu_seconds_total, i want to do an operation like,

```
input = ".*abc.*"

node_cpu_seconds_total{instance=~".*abc.*" or mode=~".*abc.*" or cpu=~".*abc.*"}
```

Basically i want my regex to be compared with all label values . Is there any solution to  achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with [vector selectors](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors) but you can use [union operator `OR`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) to get the union of selections:

```
node_cpu_seconds_total{instance=~".*abc.*"} or \
node_cpu_seconds_total{mode=~".*abc.*"} or \
node_cpu_seconds_total{cpu=~".*abc.*"}
```

BUT there is no `all label values` selector - meaning you have to specify all labels.

Note that this is rather an odd kind of request.

Comment: I have a requirement like how in aws console, we get results with the data that we give in search bar, it tries to match with all fields and give the results. Similarly i had to do this. Also, is there any way where i can get the labels that are coming in the query result.

Comment: Not that I know of. There may be some way in grafana.